# ng2-nouislider with ng-packgr

Tags: angular, angular-library, ng-packagr

I have my custom Angular library where I would like to implement ng2-nouislider in one of my components. Everything works fine but when I try to build my project I get this error:

> error NG8007: The property and event halves of the two-way binding 'ngModel' are not bound to the same target.

The problem is that when I remove NgModel everything works like a charm. But with it - build fails with following error above. I am importing FormsModule in my main library module so I think it's not the case. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69402206/update-to-angular-12-ng2-nouislider-not-working) question and people there come up with just [copy-paste](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69404984/16440146) solution which I would like to avoid.

---

Code:

```
          <nouislider class="day-slider"
                  [(ngModel)]="timeScheduleData[daySchedule.alias]"
                  [attr.id]="'slider_' + daySchedule.alias"
                  [config]="timeScheduleConfig"
                  [connect]="connectors[daySchedule.alias]"
                  [disabled]="disable"
                  (slide)="onSlide($event, daySchedule.alias)"
                  (end)="onChangeSlider($event, daySchedule.alias)"
                  (click)="onClickSlider($event, daySchedule.alias)">
      </nouislider>
```

### Any workarounds on this?

Versions:

- angular: 13.3.12
- ng-packagr: 13.3.1,
- ng2-nouislider: 1.8.3